# Fatal error after declaring function abstract

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract

I have a problem with an error I am getting that says: 
Class Car contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be decla
red abstract or implement the remaining methods (Car::accelerate) in C:\xampp
\htdocs\php\learn_php_oop\Car.php on line 58.

This is the code in two files I am using:

Car.php

```
<?php
/**
* represents generic properties and methods for any type of car
*/
class Car
{
 protected $colour, $doorNumber, $fuelType, $rightHandDrive, $accelerate;

 public function __construct($rightHandDrive = true)
 {
  $this->rightHandDrive = $rightHandDrive;
 }

 public function getColour()
 {
  return $this->colour;
 }

 public function setColour($colour)
 {
  $this->colour = $colour;
 }

 public function getDoorNumber()
 {
  return $this->doorNumber;
 }

 public function setDoorNumber($doorNumber)
 {
  $this->doorNumber = $doorNumber;
 }

 public function getFuelType()
 {
  return $this->fuelType;
 }

 public function setFuelType($fuelType)
 {
  $this->fuelType = $fuelType;
 }

 public function getRightHandDrive()
 {
  return $this->rightHandDrive;
 }

 public function setRightHandDrive($rightHandDrive)
 {
  $this->rightHandDrive = $rightHandDrive;
 }

 abstract protected function accelerate();

}
?>
```

Sport_car.php

```
<?php

include ('Car.php');
/**
 * represents sport cars
*/
class Sport_car extends Car
{

 public function accelerate()
 {
  $this->accelerate = 5;
 }

}
?>
```

I have spent some time trying to figure out why this is happening but I just do not know why? Please help.

Comment: Because your car Object is not declared as abstract class

Comment: Add abstract keyword to define an abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an OOP problem, in your case you must declare your Car Object as Abstract like this :

```
<?php
/**
* represents generic properties and methods for any type of car
*/
abstract class Car
{
 protected $colour, $doorNumber, $fuelType, $rightHandDrive, $accelerate;

 public function __construct($rightHandDrive = true)
 {
  $this->rightHandDrive = $rightHandDrive;
 }

 public function getColour()
 {
  return $this->colour;
 }

 public function setColour($colour)
 {
  $this->colour = $colour;
 }

 public function getDoorNumber()
 {
  return $this->doorNumber;
 }

 public function setDoorNumber($doorNumber)
 {
  $this->doorNumber = $doorNumber;
 }

 public function getFuelType()
 {
  return $this->fuelType;
 }

 public function setFuelType($fuelType)
 {
  $this->fuelType = $fuelType;
 }

 public function getRightHandDrive()
 {
  return $this->rightHandDrive;
 }

 public function setRightHandDrive($rightHandDrive)
 {
  $this->rightHandDrive = $rightHandDrive;
 }

 abstract protected function accelerate();

}
?>
```

Explanations :

A class wich is extended with at least one abstract method in it has to be defined as abstract itself, otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: Just correct me if I am wrong. Whenever I have an abstract method, the class containing that method also must be declared abstract.

Comment: Exactly ! it's what I said, I think.

Comment: no problem, if this solved your problem, you can accept this answer as correct answer, an upvote will be nice too :)

Comment: I did solve the problem but I need to wait 4 minutes to mark it as correct answer. For upvoting I need at least reputatation  15.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right enjoy Stack overflow then :)